# How to add short description in WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Thanks for reading, Just had a issue regarding WooCommerce, I want to add a short description checkout page of below billing field.

How to add short description in WooCommerce checkout page of below billing field?

I tried add function, custom code but failed with error.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'wc_checkout_description_so_27900033', 10, 2 );

function wc_checkout_description_so_27900033( $other_data, $cart_item )
{
    $post_data = get_post( $cart_item['product_id'] );
    $other_data[] = array( 'name' =>  'description', 'value' => $post_data->post_excerpt );
    return $other_data;
}
```

I was used this code but it is showing inner product info table.

[image]

Comment: What was the error you got when you tried to use this function?

Comment: thanks for reponse! and i'm sorry that my english skill not good cause i'm korean. the code don't show where I want. this code is showing only in "<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">". I want to show it where I want.

Comment: If you have multiple items in the cart, how do you decide which product description to show?

Comment: This is a ticket reservation. So it can not checkout for multiple products at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no real reason to call `get_post()`. The `$product` object is stored in the `$cart_item` array and the `$post` object is stored inside the `$product`. This gets the product's excerpt (aka the short description) to show up in the cart and in the checkout. Now, it isn't likely the make the description show up on the order received page, or in the my account area, or in emails, etc since the only place that the `woocommerce_get_item_data` filter appears is in the cart class.

One thing to take note of, WooCommerce 2.7 is a major rewrite of WooCommerce and `$_product->post->post_excerpt` will result in PHP notices about directly accessing product properties. So I've suggested both the 2.6 and 2.7 compatible approaches.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'wc_checkout_description_so_27900033', 10, 2 );

function wc_checkout_description_so_27900033( $other_data, $cart_item )
{
    $_product = $cart_item['data'];
    // Use this for WC2.7
    //$other_data[] = array( 'name' =>  'description', 'value' => $_product->get_short_description() );

    // Use this for WC2.6
    $other_data[] = array( 'name' =>  'description', 'value' => $_product->post->post_excerpt );

    return $other_data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I'll try this code: )well..this code is add where i want? My problem is the code showing in product table

Comment: Yes, this code will show the description in the product table. Please edit your question to describe (a picture might help) where you *want* the description to be displayed.

Comment: sorry for not enough explanation. now i add a picture.